# No module named django-admin C:\Program Files\Python39\python3.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.7, python-3.9

I have 2 python installed in my windows10.

1 -
`python 3.7.x`

2 -
`python 3.9.x`

I have these **2 versions** because I simultaneously work on **different Django versions on my laptop**.

**NOTE:** I have renamed **python.exe** to **python3.exe** for the **version of 3.9.x**

and kept **python.exe for 3.7.x** as it is.

To run my `Django == 2.x.x` project, I write:

`python manage.py runserver`

To run my
`Django == 3.9.x`  project, I write:

`python3 manage.py runserver`

But when I try to create a new project using:

```
python3 -m django-admin startproject my_project_name
```

It gives me an error of `No module name django-admin`
I don't know why it gives me this error.
can anyone guide me?

Comment: Your django is probably installed for python2.x and not 3

Comment: I have 2 different python versions at the same time

Comment: and I think I have fixed the issue

Comment: @djangodeveloper you have to tell how you solve it. Since it is a question.

Comment: I was trying django-admin startproject project_name but was not working.
so I tried python3 -m django-admin startproject projectname, still didn't worked.

Comment: what I did, is changed my root directory to venv/Scripts and ran the command like this "" djangp-admin startproject project_name" and it worked there. so I deleted this and came back to the root directory and then tried django-admin startproject project_name

Comment: I didn't understand the logic behind it but it worked this way. I am still confused about how it can work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess renaming the file doesn't actually renames the directory locator of compiler

Instead why not create a virtual environment within Python3, and pip install Django==3.x within that.

It's always better to create virtual environment if you have multiple compilers

Comment: yeah, that's a correct answer. I have already mentioned in the comment that I created the project within the python3